# Как добавить InlineKeyboardMarkup aiogram для MediaGroup?

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Я пытаюсь создать альбом с пагинацией в своем телеграм боте, у пользователя есть в базе данный ссылки на изображения, их достаточно много, и я хочу сделать это в виде альбома, потому что разом отправить все изображения - это напряжно, так еще и ориентироваться пользователю в этом сложно... Я отправляю группу изображений по 10 штук с помощью метода answer_media_group, но в документации у этого метода не предусмотрен параметр reply_keyboard. Делать пагинацию по одному изображению тоже не вариант, так как это можно реализовать?

```
media = []
for url in cats_urls:
    group_member = InputMediaPhoto(type='photo', media=url)
    media.append(group_member)
await message.answer_media_group(media=media)
```

Вот после media, я хочу написать reply_keyboard, но написав и передав клавиатуру, у меня не появляется клавиатура, и ошибки также нет

Comment: Клавиатуру нельзя прицепить к медиагруппе. Это не предусмотрено Bot API, поэтому и в документации aiogram тоже этого нет

Comment: Хорошо, а как это можно обойти, если мне необходимо реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: Ну отправляйте 2 сообщения. Сначала медиагруппу, затем сообщение с клавиатурой